# How to copy (or move) a file to a folder that is not existing while i am performing the copy (or move) operation?

Tags: command-line

Say I want to copy a file `batman.py` from `path1/batman.py` to `path2/` .

While copying I want to create a directory inside `path2` and the copy `batman.py` inside the new directory there.

How can I do it while performing the copy operation?

(That is make a directory and copy into that directory in same command).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`install`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install) command given file or a full directory to a given location.

```
install -D sample.txt /path-to-create/sample.txt
```

for your case

```
install -D path1/batman.py path2/batman.py
```

If path2 doesn't exist then it will create it

---

In case of moving there is no single command to do that so you should use `mkdir` and `mv` to ensure that.

But you can make this simple trick.

create a function

```
mkmv () {
  mkdir -p "$2"
  mv "$1" "$2/$1"
}
```

Now add this function to your `.bashrc`

after that run the command

```
source .bashrc
```

Hot to use the command?

After adding the function to `.bashrc` you can easily use the command in your termianl

```
mkmv batman.py path2
```

$1=batman.py

$2=path2

Now if path2 doesn't exist then it will create and then move the file inside

Comment: thank you!  it is useful.   
 i have one more doubt, this is doing to copy operation right...? what if i want to move from path1 ?

Comment: `install` works for copy not move. In case of move you can use the regular `mv` command

Comment: how to move to a path that dont exits now?

Comment: This is another question.. just ask it and i'll answer to help others... but simply you can use mkdir -p to create the path and then mv

Comment: okay, i thought i mentioned the moving part too in the question.
thank you

Comment: @srkcb89 Check the edit